Did it make sense for me to make a "clarifying" bid or should I have jumped directly to game?
With neither vulnerable at matchpoints, I opened one diamond in fourth seat with the following:  ♠87 ♥A964 ♦AKQT54 ♣6.
Partner raised to 2NT (10-12 points invitational) with the following: ♠KQ ♥KQ5 ♦9876 ♣QT85.
I felt the need to clarify my hand, so I rebid 3 diamonds, showing six diamonds and 12+ high card points. My two questions were: 1) "Do you have a full 12," and 2)do you have a stopper in every suit? I feared that he could have made the same 2NT bid with ♠KQ ♥KQ5 ♦9876 ♣T985.
Although he eould answer my questions in the affirmative, he passed and we got a bottom. In bidding as I did, I feared the weakness of my two black suit holdings. With better balance, say  ♠874 ♥A96 ♦AKQT54 ♣6, I would gone directly to 3NT.
Should I have done this anyway? Was it ok for me to clarify my hand? Or could I even have used a "gambling" 3NT opening (after clarifying it with partner).

What's your agreement on what your 3D bid meant?  In particular, is it forcing?  A re-invite?  Meant to be passed?

Many top pros would open a 15-17 1N with your hand, particularly if playing with a mediocre client.  Your hand is that good.

3H bid would suggest concern about C and/or S stoppers ( but this is also helpful information for the opposition), 3D normally indicates opener is light with 6 diamonds and suggests passing. It’s only worth using a clarifying bid when clarity is more useful to you than to your opponents.

Stop imagining disasters around very corner, and just bid 3NT. If you're going down there, you won't be alone. Bid with the field, and save "taking a view" for the play, when the facts are clearer and more abundant. You are already unlucky in that partner has only 4 clubs, rather than 5 or even 6 on this auction, and 3 NT is still icy. Game in diamonds is also ice cold, though it likely won't pay as well as 3 NT.
Further, your interpretation of 3 Diamonds is incorrect: it should show both a long broken diamond suit and minimum. You are neither.
As for opening 3 NT - just don't. That promises nothing outside the running suit, and you have a very nice heart ace.

If I have a six card suit, and they are AKQxxx, the suit is not "broken." If one of the top honors is missing, say the K, then the suit IS broken. I have seven high card points outside of diamonds, which can protect at least two, if not all three of the side suits. In this instance, if I have 13 hcps and hear 2NT (10-12), partner and I are 13-10, 13-11, or 13-12 in points, with all four suits likely covered.  Is 23 point enough for 3NT? Probably not,, So I bid 3 diamonds and ask, 1) do you have a minimum or maximum? and 2) do you have all four suits protected, since I am short in at least one?

@TomAu - If your partner has Axx xxx xxx Axxx, then you will make 3N (assuming diamonds don't split 4-0).  Actually, if partner has Axx Kxx xxx xxxx you probably make 3N (since clubs won't split worse than 4-3).  You have 7 tricks in hand.  Is partner likely to have 2 tricks even if they only have 10 points?  Yes.  Don't just blindly count points.  Visualize possible hands (bad ones as well as good ones) for partner and count tricks.

@AlexanderWoo: That would be the rationale for a "gambling" 3NT. Partner is expected to provide two winners and one stopper (Jxxx will do) in the two majors and in one of the minors, because I have seven winners, either seven diamonds, or six diamonds and a side winner.

Actually, four clubs for partner (and each opponent) is "average expectations" for suit length, given that I have one. But their average quality is something like KT73, which is better than both partner's actual holding, and my hypothetical T985.

Do you mean an actual "gambling 3N", as in the convention where opening 3N shows a hand with a running minor (and some agreement about strength outside the minor which varies between partnerships)?  Or do you just mean an ordinary odds-on gamble of 3N?

A lot depends on your style and understandings with partner. There are two basic styles in reaching game: the direct style and the "careful" style. While they both have their advantages, every partnership has to agree on its preferences and priorities.
I was with a new partner who favors the "direct" style. That is, he likes to go to the final contract, as soon as one reasonably can, based on a critical mass of bidding.. This style has the advantages of being "fast" and reasonably accurate. And it avoids the chance of misunderstanding as happened here.
Other good players in the club prefer to "dot the i's and cross the t's. These people would agree with me, that there was a specific concern, that is two wide-open black suits, and that partner would cover only one of them. This might be the case if partner held only  ♠KQ ♥KQ5 ♦9876 ♣T985, a minimum hand for his bid, instead of his actual holding. In this case, partner should choose a contract of five diamonds (although that would have shared a bottom if we had bid it).
My partner is one of the better players in the club, so I will do well to fit in with his style. With this partner, I will now go directly to 3NT.

At matchpoints, you want to be in 3N than 5m, even if it's sometimes wrong double-dummy.  Defenders will make the wrong opening lead or otherwise misdefend frequently enough for you to be ahead playing 3N.  You would rather be +430 55% of the time and -50 45% of the time than be +400/420 100% of the time.
